Deployment with docker compose and github actions
I'm deploying my docker compose with github actions and I keep getting this error whenever I try to push a new version of my docker image to prod. I have a strapi and a backend container. Thank you very much
err: time="2024-11-15T00:00:35Z" level=warning msg="Found orphan containers ([***-strapi-1 ***-***-1]) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up."
err:  Container ***-api-1  Recreate
err: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/9adc414c29fa_***-api-1" is already in use by container "7a7ecc21b86171712f550001ba9b9dbf84b4a4b55cdcfe8a3d74f46608121e88". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.

Here's my docker compose file for prod
name: Deploy prod stack to DigitalOcean

on:
  create:
    branches:
      - release
  push:
    branches:
      - release
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - release

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checking out the repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Copy docker-compose-api.prod.yml over to the server
        uses: appleboy/scp-action@v0.1.7
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}
          passphrase: ${{ secrets.PASSPHRASE }}
          source: "docker-compose-api.prod.yml"
          target: /home/${{ secrets.USERNAME }}

      - name: Run the docker-compose-api.prod.yml stack
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.6
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}
          passphrase: ${{ secrets.PASSPHRASE }}
          script: |
            echo ${{ secrets.CR_PAT }} | docker login ghcr.io -u ${{ github.actor }} --password-stdin
            export DATABASE_HOST=${{ secrets.DATABASE_HOST }}
            export DATABASE_PORT=${{ secrets.DATABASE_PORT }}
            export DATABASE_NAME=${{ secrets.SERVER_DATABASE_NAME }}
            export DATABASE_USERNAME=${{ secrets.DATABASE_USERNAME }}
            export DATABASE_PASSWORD=${{ secrets.DATABASE_PASSWORD }}
            export RABBITMQ_HOST=${{ secrets.RABBITMQ_HOST }}
            export RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=${{ secrets.RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER }}
            export RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=${{ secrets.RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASSWORD }}
            export RABBITMQ_QUEUE=${{ secrets.RABBITMQ_QUEUE }}
            export SENDGRID_APIKEY=${{ secrets.SENDGRID_APIKEY }}
            export SENDGRID_SENDER_EMAIL=${{ secrets.SENDGRID_SENDER_EMAIL }}
            export GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY=${{ secrets.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY }}
            export ADMIN_DELIVERY_DRIVER_EMAIL=${{ vars.ADMIN_DELIVERY_DRIVER_EMAIL }}
            docker compose -f docker-compose-api.prod.yml pull
            docker compose -f docker-compose-api.prod.yml up -d --force-recreate


I think you are running an older version of docker, try to update it. With that older version seems you can't recreate container until you stop existing one. So as workaround you might just run docker compose -f docker-compose-api.prod.yml stop prior docker compose -f docker-compose-api.prod.yml up -d --force-recreate

I'm using docker version 27

Hi! So have you tried to run docker compose -f docker-compose-api.prod.yml stop prior docker compose -f docker-compose-api.prod.yml up -d --force-recreate. I don't see how you install docker on your github action code. Can you share that part with me?
